# Alternative to CURL due to long waiting

Tags: php, curl

I currently run a PHP-script using CURL to send data to another server, to do run a PHP-script that could take up to a minute to run.
This server doesn't give any data back. But the CURL-request still has to wait for it to complete, and then it loads the rest of the orignal page. I would like my PHP-script to just send the data to the other server and then not wait for an answer.

So my question is how should I solve this? I have read that CURL always has to wait. What are your suggestions?

Comment: @ChristopheD I wouldn't have said this is a duplicate at all.

Comment: @Yacoby: After reflecting I agree that different approaches could be taken here and this might not completely fit the 'duplicate' tag. Solutionwise, the proposed solutions from the other thread; using `exec` to run the php-curl file (with an ampersand appended to make it a background process) would work on Linux though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be a useful starting point, flagrantly [copypasted from here](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2008/06/how-to-post-an.html)

```
function curl_post_async($url, $params)
{
    $post_string = http_build_query($params);

    $parts=parse_url($url);

    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], 
        isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80, 
        $errno, $errstr, 30);

    //pete_assert(($fp!=0), "Couldn't open a socket to ".$url." (".$errstr.")");(optional)

    $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
    $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    if (isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: This is better than CURL with `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` set to `1` because if the connection is not established with the said server within 1 second then your HTTP call fails silently.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)
\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a server socket on the other machine that your PHP web page connects to. This way, you decide the protocol. Otherwise, look to see if a background process meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can set the max execution time in php so it will stop the script working after the time limit. It's not a "pro" solution but it works !

Answer (score -1):

It's simply better to use the TIMEOUT flag to exit within a time frame.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, sec); // sec is int variable
```

That was C code, adapt yourself up.