# How to make cURL function curl_exec to work under Server with restricted permissions?

Tags: php, curl, yii, bookmarklet

I have been developing a bookmarklet, and at some point this app has to load a webpage content.

For the last 8 months, i have been developing the app on a server that does not have limitations.

Now, i had to setup the app on another server, in order for the client to try it.

I got into trouble with cURL, with the following code, with the fetchContent function;

If you run my app under wamp, xamp, lamp, on localhost, it runs perfect;

On the new server, where i configured the app for the client, we cant use cURL, because of the function

```
$content = curl_exec($curl);
```

And, the options array, does not load;

First, our new server did not allow us to send data, using $_GET method with JSON.stringify data;

We have deactivated a strange security plugin for our app, that did not allowed any JSON.stringify data to be passed as input , and now the server accepts the input;

We get a 52 error code, with value 1;

```
CURLE_GOT_NOTHING (52)

Nothing was returned from the server, and under the circumstances, getting nothing is considered an error.
```

Then we found out about: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#95027
 but this does not work, even after correcting the author little mistake and after i adapted the code;

And what's the role of open_basedir in all this cURl stuff ?

this is my code:

```
<?php

class CurlTool {

    public static $userAgents = array(
        'FireFox3' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0',
        'GoogleBot' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
        'IE7' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)',
        'Netscape' => 'Mozilla/4.8 [en] (Windows NT 6.0; U)',
        'Opera' => 'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en)'
    );
    public static $options = array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)',
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookies.txt",
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookies.txt",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            //CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => false,
    );
    private static $proxyServers = array();
    private static $proxyCount = 0;
    private static $currentProxyIndex = 0;
    public static $getinfo;

    public static function addProxyServer($url) {
        self::$proxyServers[] = $url;
        ++self::$proxyCount;
    }

    public static function fetchContent($url, $fields = null, $verbose = false) {
        //print '*'.$fields.'*';
        if (($curl = curl_init($url)) == false) {
            throw new Exception("curl_init error for url $url.");
        }
        if (self::$proxyCount > 0) {
            $proxy = self::$proxyServers[self::$currentProxyIndex++ % self::$proxyCount];
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            if ($verbose === true) {
                echo "Reading $url [Proxy: $proxy] ... ";
            }
        } else if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Reading $url ... ";
        }
        //$verbose=TRUE;
        //print_r($fields);
//        debug_print_backtrace();
//url-ify the data for the POST
        $fields_string = '';
        if (is_array($fields))
            foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($key))
                    continue;
                $fields_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
                if ($verbose === true) {
                    echo $key . ": " . $value;
                }
            }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        if (count($fields) > 0) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        }

        if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Fields string $fields_string ... ";
        }

        curl_setopt_array($curl, self::$options);

        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        self::$getinfo = curl_getinfo($curl);
        if ($content === false) {
            throw new Exception("curl_exec error for url $url " . curl_error($curl));
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Done.\n";
        }
        $content = preg_replace('#\n+#', ' ', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('#\s+#', ' ', $content);

        return $content;
    }

    public static function downloadFile($url, $fileName, $fields = null, $verbose = false) {
        if (($curl = curl_init($url)) == false) {
            throw new Exception("curl_init error for url $url.");
        }


        if (self::$proxyCount > 0) {
            $proxy = self::$proxyServers[self::$currentProxyIndex++ % self::$proxyCount];
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            if ($verbose === true) {
                echo "Downloading $url [Proxy: $proxy] ... ";
            }
        } else if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Downloading $url ... ";
        }

        //url-ify the data for the POST
        $fields_string = '';
        if (is_array($fields))
            foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($key))
                    continue;
                $fields_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
            }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        curl_setopt_array($curl, self::$options);

        if (is_file($fileName)) {
            $contents = file_get_contents($fileName, false, null, -1, 3 * 1024);
            $pattern = "__VIEWSTATE";
            if (strpos($contents, $pattern) === false) {
                return $fileName;
            }
        }

//        if (is_file($fileName)) {
//            // make a HEAD request and try to get the file size HEAD
//            // if they differ then redownload the file, otherwise no need
//            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
//            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
//            $ret = curl_exec($curl);
//            //echo $fileName;
//            $size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
//            if ($size == filesize($fileName)) {
//                return $fileName;
//            } else {
//                unlink($fileName);
//                return self::downloadFile($url, $fileName, $fields, $verbose);
//            }
//        }

        if (substr($fileName, -1) == '/') {
            $targetDir = $fileName;
            $fileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'c_');
        }
        if (($fp = fopen('./files/'.$fileName, "w")) === false) {
            throw new Exception("fopen error for filename $fileName");
        }



        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

        $ret = curl_exec($curl);
        self::$getinfo = curl_getinfo($curl);

        if ($ret === false) {
            fclose($fp);
            unlink($fileName);
            throw new Exception("curl_exec error for url $url.");
        } elseif (isset($targetDir)) {
            $eurl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
            preg_match('#^.*/(.+)$#', $eurl, $match);
            fclose($fp);
            rename($fileName, "$targetDir{$match[1]}");
            $fileName = "$targetDir{$match[1]}";
        } else {
            fclose($fp);
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Done.\n";
        }
        return $fileName;
    }

}
```

Comment: The CURL is not enabled on your new server? If not, why?

Comment: it is enabled, but it has limitations, and the admis cant set the entire server to run after my app specs

Comment: You are using Yii correct?

Try using this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restclient/

Comment: How about just opening a socket directly as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2822936/2097149 ?

Comment: will try also this one, thank you